# Finding difficulty in scraping a specific field using lxml or beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, lxml, screen-scraping

I am new in scraping can you guide me how to get price ("299.00") from following html using python lxml or beautifulsoup?

HTML CODE image is attached

[Click to See Html code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z42c.png)

```
    from lxml import html
    import requests

    url="https://world.taobao.com/item/537221576985.htm?fromSite=main&spm=a21ct.7779917.1441024229133.8.AvoEs0"
    page=requests.get(url)
    tree=html.fromstring(page.text)


    price=tree.xpath('//strong[@class="tb-rmb-num"]/text()')

    print(price)
```

Comment: It looks like `.price strong` should work, I think both libs can do that.

Comment: I think I have found the real issue, actually on product page price loads when browser opens it (probably website use javascript) that's why it was not getting price.I think requests get only html which is availabe at that moment so  I used selenium to open page in browser and then used above code to get price.